# C++ variadic template empty argument specialization

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

What's the correct way to write a specialization for an empty argument variadic template. Take bellow code as an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

struct message {
    int type;
};

struct X: message {
    int payload;
    X(): message{1} {
    }
};

struct Y: message {
    int payload;
    Y(): message{2} {
    }
};

struct Z: message {
    int payload;
    Z(): message{3} {
    }
};

template<typename T>
constexpr int message_type = -1;

template<>
constexpr int message_type<X> = 1;

template<>
constexpr int message_type<Y> = 2;

template<>
constexpr int message_type<Z> = 3;

struct M {
    int payload;
    M(int payload): payload{ payload } {
    }
};

template<typename P, typename T1, typename... Ts>
tuple<int, unique_ptr<M>> helper(unique_ptr<message> &msg, function<int(unique_ptr<T1>&)> fn1, function<int(unique_ptr<Ts>&)>... fn) {
    if (msg->type == message_type<T1>) {
        unique_ptr<T1> m(static_cast<T1*>(msg.release()));
        auto result = fn1(m);
        return {result, make_unique<M>(m->payload)};
    } else {
        return helper<void, Ts...>(msg, fn...);
    }
}

template<typename P>
tuple<int, unique_ptr<M>> helper(unique_ptr<message> &msg) {
    assert(false);
    return {0, unique_ptr<M>()};
}

template<typename... Ts>
tuple<int, unique_ptr<M>> dispatch_msg(unique_ptr<message> &msg, function<int(unique_ptr<Ts>&)> ...fn) {
    return helper<void, Ts...>(msg, fn...);
}

int main() {
    auto *real_message = new Z;
    real_message->payload = 101;

    unique_ptr<message> msg(real_message);

    auto [result, m] = dispatch_msg<X, Y, Z>(msg, [](auto &x) {
        return x->payload + 1;
    }, [](auto &y) {
        return y->payload + 2;
    }, [](auto &z) {
        return z->payload + 3;
    });
    cout << result << '\n' << m->payload << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The `helper` function takes variadic template arguments. If it checked all given type arguments and failed. e.g. run to the empty arguments. I want to assert and stop the process.
The current code works but I'm wondering is there any straightforward way to write a specialization.

I simplified the core requirements into the code below:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void func(int val, T arg, Ts... args) {
    if (condition_hold<T>(val)) {
        return;
    } else {
        return func<Ts...>(val, args...);
    }
}

template<>
void func(int val) {
    assert(false);
}

int main() {
    func<int, double, float>(100);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically the `func` is checking against every given type whether a condition hold for the input `val`. If all check failed I want to do something, like the `assert` here. So I wrote a specialization takes empty argument, but this can't compile.

Comment: A very, very careful search of the shown code find no evidence of any existence of the `help()` function that you are asking about in your question. It should be possible for you replace the shown code with a much easier to read [mre] that uses simple types, instead of all of these complicated ones, to demonstrate the C++ principle or concept you're asking about.

Comment: How about `std::variant<X, Y, Z>`? [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5eac2e7bffbbc0b).

Comment: Can you use C++17?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik should be `helper` function. Let me simplify it later.

Comment: what is `unique_ptr<M>` supposed to be for? It seems to just be another wrapper for the result

Comment: @JanSchultke Please refer to the simplified code, it can't compile even in C++20. The unique_ptr<M> in the original code is just a demo for using the input, can simply ignore it. The simplified code is more suitable for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17, you don't need to split parameter packs into head and tail in most cases. Thanks to [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), many operations on packs become much easier.

```cpp
// Some generic predicate.
template <typename T>
bool condition_hold(T) {
    return true;
}

// Make this whatever you want.
void do_something_with(int);

template<typename... Ts>
auto func(int val, Ts... args) {
    // Fold expression checks whether the condition is true for all
    // elements of the parameter pack.
    // Will be true if the parameter pack is empty.
    if ((condition_hold(args) && ...))
        do_something_with(val);
}

int main() {
    // Ts type parameters are deduced to <float, float>.
    func(100, 1.f, 2.f);
    return 0;
}
```

To check whether the pack was empty and handle this case specially, you can do:

```cpp
template<typename... Ts>
auto func(int val, Ts... args) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) == 0) {
        // handle empty pack
    }
    else {
        // handle non-empty pack
    }
}
```

Your specialization couldn't have worked because `func<>` needs to take at least one parameter. A specialization such as

```cpp
template<typename T>
void func<T>(int val);
```

Wouldn't be valid either, because it wold be a partial specialization which is only allowed for classes.
However, if the base template only takes a pack, we can fully specialize it:

```cpp
template<typename... Ts>
void func(int val, Ts... args);

template<>
void func<>(int val);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but seems in this approach, we can't know which type makes the condition hold? One possible solution I came up with is that we can put the computation into the condition check function, but this way we can't retrieve the computation result.

Comment: @libo isn't the computation result only coming from the `int`? I thought all the other parameters are only for testing whether the condition holds true. But what you have described is also possible. But if there are multiple computation results, which one should be returned?

Comment: The computation result only comes from the `int`. Only one type argument can make the condition hold, I need to do some computation based on the type that makes the condition hold. In the real case, it's a class type, not a plain `int`, I need to do some typecast when the condition hold. I just thought about it again. In the condition check function, when the condition hold I know the type and the val, so I can do my computation. To get the computation result I can pass in one additional container to store the result.